# UISwitch - UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiswitch

I have this tableView:

[image: Image1]

but I can't recognize when user selects the UISwitch in the row.
I know I need an @IBAction in the UITableViewCell class but I didn't found a guide that works for me.
I'd like to print the indexPath of the row when user clicks on the UISwitch.

This is my class for cell:

```
class TicketsFilterCell: UITableViewCell {


@IBOutlet weak var textFilter: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var switchFilter: UISwitch!


class var reuseIdentifier: String? {
    get {
        return "TicketsFilterCell"
    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

}

}
```

How can I do?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

My cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    let cell: TicketsFilterCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellTicketFilter", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? TicketsFilterCell

    cell?.delegate = self

    if(indexPath.section == 0) {

        let text = status[indexPath.row]?.capitalizedString

        cell?.textFilter.text = text


    } else if(indexPath.section == 1) {

        let text = queues [indexPath.row]?.capitalizedString

        cell?.textFilter.text = text

    } else if(indexPath.section == 2) {

        let text = types[indexPath.row]?.capitalizedString

        cell?.textFilter.text = text

    } else if(indexPath.section == 3) {

        let text = severities[indexPath.row]?.capitalizedString

        cell?.textFilter.text = text

    }



        return cell!

}
```

Comment: In the `IBAction` get the `superview` of the sender (switch) which is the table view cell. Then get the index path.

Comment: @vadian Thanks you! I'll try this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jigen,

Here is what you can do :)

Declare a protocol in your cell class lets call it as CellProtocol.

```
protocol CellProtocol : class {
    func switchButtonTapped(WithStatus status : Bool, ForCell myCell : TicketsFilterCell)
}
```

Declare a variable in your TicketsFilterCell class to hold delegate,

```
weak var delegate : CellProtocol!
```

When user taps on your switch trigger the delegate as

```
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    self.delegate .switchButtonTapped(WithStatus: selected, ForCell: self)
}
```

In your TableViewController confirm to protocol using

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController,CellProtocol {
```

Now in your ViewController's cellForRoAtIndexPath, for each cell set the delegate as self.

```
cell.delegate = self
```

Finally implement the delegate method as follow

```
func switchButtonTapped(WithStatus status: Bool, ForCell cell: TicketsFilterCell) {
        let indexPath = self.tableView .indexPathForCell(cell)
        print("cell at indexpath \(indexPath) tapped with switch status \(status)")
    }
```

**EDIT :**

For each cell you have dragged the IBOutlet for switch :) Now all you need is IBAction from UISwitch to the cell :)

```
@IBAction func switchTapped(sender: UISwitch) {
        self.delegate.switchButtonTapped(WithStatus: sender.on, ForCell: self)
    }
```

Thats it :)

Comment: @jigen : Sure buddy :)

Comment: In the protocol, what myCell means?

Comment: @jigen : Sorry myCell is the name of the cells class in your case it will be TicketsFilterCell :)

Comment: Ok I tried but I got nil on the weak var delegate: CellProtocol!. I solved setting 'protocol CellProtocol: class {...}'

Comment: @jigen : Did you set cell's delegate in cellForRowAtIndexPath as cell.delegate = self ???

Comment: but I still get nil error on the 'self.delegate.switchButtonTapped(WithStatus: selected, ForCell: self)'

Comment: @jigen : I checked the code buddy its working fine :) I would like to see little more in detail of how protocols delcared and some other stuffs But I cant start chat if you can start it and ping me :)

Comment: @jigen : No need to delete the post lemme add a link to the working code :) Download and compare if found error lemme know :)

Comment: @jigen : Have a look at this code :) https://github.com/sandeeplearner/SO-Code compare your code and find issue in your code and fix it :) If worked fine please accept the answer :)

Comment: I still get nil on the delegate... my code is the same as yours except for the cellForRowAtIndexPath where I have the if control on section..I can't explain why it doesn't work

Comment: Thats strange buddy :( I never faced anything like it before :) Anyway do two things 1. In cell?.delegate = self after this check po cell.delegate value :) 2. change  weak var delegate to var delegate :) This is the worst solution but check once :) You should not have strong reference to any class hence you specify weak but anyway try once :)

Comment: Ok I tried a clean at the end and now it prints the result but how can I see when a user clicks on a Switch?

Comment: @jigen : hehehehehehe :) I knew you would ask this :)

Comment: @jigen : Wait for a min lemme edit the answer for you :)

Comment: @jigen : Please have a look at the editted code :) If you still have issue lemme know :)

Comment: Can I open an issue on your github project to ask you the last things? This is the accepted answer obviously :)

Comment: I opened the issue :)

Comment: @jigen : And I closed it :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
cell.yourSwitch.tag=indexPath.row;
```

in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** method

Based on that tag perform your code in switch on/off action.

Comment: Thanks you, I'll try.

Answer (score 1):

Add an `@IBAction` from the switch to the view controller itself. In the IBAction function convert the position of the `sender`(UISwitch) to tableView's frame. Then, find the cell at that point in tableView.

I believe this is the most elegant way to add actions to table view cells.

- The biggest problem with the tag property is that its use always starts out simple, but over time the logic (or lack thereof) evolves into a fat unreadable mess.
- This is easier than creating a protocol and implementing the delegate

Below is the `IBAction` connected to the switch's `valueChanged` action

```
@IBAction func switchValueChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    let switchButton = sender as! UISwitch
    let buttonPosition = switchButton.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(buttonPosition)!
    NSLog("switch at index %d changed value to %@", indexPath.row, switchButton.on)
}
```